# Removing /web component from community urls using friendly url (or similar solutions)

Tags: liferay

Our site is using communities for specific subject areas of the site. For SEO reasons, we want to remove the /web component in the URL. We want to exclude this component for all of the communities in the site.

In essence, given a site.com, and a community ranging from named user[1-inf], then instead of this:
site.com/web/user1
We want to have this:
site.com/user1

For each user's public page.

I've been tampering around with layout.friendly.url.public.servlet.mapping, giving it an empty string and replacing the corresponding lines in the web.xml file, but this solution doesn't work at all.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Currently using liferay 6.2
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was for a single site, you should explore the "virtual host" setting in a site which removes the whole "/web/site-name" part and assigns this to a unique hostname (or "/group/site-name" for private pages).

As you're asking for *all* user accounts, this is a bit harder. Some solutions that come to mind:

- If you have a limited amount of users and rarely add new ones, Apache-Level Rewrites might make sense.
- A ServletFilter (which you can add as a plugin) could help resolving the required pages and rewrite internal to Liferay. This has the advantage of being totally responsive to the currently existing user accounts - as soon as you have a new user, you can resolve their pages. Make sure to disallow usernames though that would clash with Liferay paths - e.g. "c", "web", "group", "images", "html" etc.
- If you want all the links internally generated to the user's homepage to point to your changed locations, you might need to override some of Liferay's services. You'll have to find the places where the URLs are generated (if not read from db) and override it. I'm expecting that a simple service override will suffice, but haven't looked at it

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there was a simpler solution, but it seems that your #2 and #3 suggestions will be the only to deal with it, as we have a significant number of users and new accounts.

Answer (score 0):

in your .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /web [L]`

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: Is mod rewrite engine enabled on your web server?

Comment: Yep, I'm using it for other stuff as well, so it's definitely working.